# Shortest path performance in Graphx with Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am creating a graph from a `gz` compressed `json` file of `edge` and `vertices` type.

I have put the files in a dropbox folder [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9ug5ikr6j357q7j/AACDBR9UdM0g_ck_ykB8KXPXa?dl=0)

I load and map these `json` records to create the `vertices` and `edge` types required by `graphx` like this:

```
val vertices_raw = sqlContext.read.json("path/vertices.json.gz")
val vertices = vertices_raw.rdd.map(row=> ((row.getAs[String]("toid").stripPrefix("osgb").toLong),row.getAs[Long]("index")))
val verticesRDD: RDD[(VertexId, Long)] = vertices
val edges_raw = sqlContext.read.json("path/edges.json.gz")
val edgesRDD = edges_raw.rdd.map(row=>(Edge(row.getAs[String]("positiveNode").stripPrefix("osgb").toLong, row.getAs[String]("negativeNode").stripPrefix("osgb").toLong, row.getAs[Double]("length"))))
val my_graph: Graph[(Long),Double] = Graph.apply(verticesRDD, edgesRDD).partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut)
```

I then use this `dijkstra` implementation I found to compute a shortest path between two vertices:

```
def dijkstra[VD](g: Graph[VD, Double], origin: VertexId) = {
          var g2 = g.mapVertices(
        (vid, vd) => (false, if (vid == origin) 0 else Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]())
          )
          for (i <- 1L to g.vertices.count - 1) {
            val currentVertexId: VertexId = g2.vertices.filter(!_._2._1)
              .fold((0L, (false, Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]())))(
                (a, b) => if (a._2._2 < b._2._2) a else b)
              ._1

            val newDistances: VertexRDD[(Double, List[VertexId])] =
              g2.aggregateMessages[(Double, List[VertexId])](
            ctx => if (ctx.srcId == currentVertexId) {
              ctx.sendToDst((ctx.srcAttr._2 + ctx.attr, ctx.srcAttr._3 :+ ctx.srcId))
            },
            (a, b) => if (a._1 < b._1) a else b
          )
        g2 = g2.outerJoinVertices(newDistances)((vid, vd, newSum) => {
          val newSumVal = newSum.getOrElse((Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]()))
          (
            vd._1 || vid == currentVertexId,
            math.min(vd._2, newSumVal._1),
            if (vd._2 < newSumVal._1) vd._3 else newSumVal._2
            )
        })
        }

          g.outerJoinVertices(g2.vertices)((vid, vd, dist) =>
        (vd, dist.getOrElse((false, Double.MaxValue, List[VertexId]()))
          .productIterator.toList.tail
          ))
        }
```

I take two random vertex id's:

```
val v1 = 4000000028222916L
val v2 = 4000000031019012L
```

and compute the path between them:

```
val results = dijkstra(my_graph, v1).vertices.map(_._2).collect
```

I am unable to compute this locally on my laptop without getting a stackoverflow error. I can see that it is using 3 out of 4 cores available. I can load this graph and compute shortest 10 paths per second with the `igraph` library in Python on exactly the same graph. Is this an inefficient means of computing paths? At scale, on multiple nodes the paths will compute (no stackoverflow error) but it is still 30/40seconds per path computation.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on the [python-igraph github](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph)

> "It is intended to be as powerful (ie. fast) as possible to enable the
>   analysis of large graphs."

In order to explain why it is taking 4000x more time on apache-spark than on local python, you may take a look [here](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/investigating-sparks-performance) (A deep dive into performance bottlenecks with Spark PMC member Kay Ousterhout.) to see that it is probably due to a bottleneck:

> ... beginning with the idea that network and disk I/O are major bottlenecks ...
>   You may not need to store your data in-memory because the job may not get that much faster. This is saying that if you moved the serialized compressed data from on-disk to in-memory...

you may also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254668/is-cpu-the-real-performance-bottleneck-of-spark) & [here](http://blog.octo.com/en/the-evolution-of-bottlenecks-in-the-big-data-ecosystem/) some informations , but best final method is to *benchmark your code to know where the bottleneck is*.